# Azure B2C SSO for my web application and powerapps application not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, powerapps

I have configured my Azure B2C to enable SSO feature, after enable when I login into my web application and redirect to power apps application it does not show as logged in instead it is showing for SIGN IN and when click on that button it directly logged my account and create cookie of **.AspNet.ApplicationCookie** and show account details. Both web application and power app have different domains. Please help me what I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s expected, since you have to send the user to AAD B2C to check if they are logged in. The user must perform an action in App2 to be sent to B2C to perform the login or SSO.

You could perform a check on page load using a hidden iframe and if the login works, do something to update the page to reflect that, otherwise silently fail.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-user-flow

This would require coding in the authentication with MSAL into the app.

Comment: is there any option to pass session cookie from one tab to another by using msal.js or any javascript code or C# code, as azure b2c is using user flow not custom policy

Comment: The session cookie is loaded when you call loginRedirect(). You can call loginRedirect() in an iframe.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue for power apps application and it is working by using iframe, but same I am trying into c# web application it is throwing below error :
`Refused to frame '<azure b2c url>' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors <my sites url>". `

Comment: Inside the custom policy you state what URLs to allow in the iframe to load from (under JourneyFraming tag), make sure your website URL is listed.

Comment: Hi @Jas Suri
It was working smoothly on all browser, but after new upgrade of chrome and firefox browser, it stop working into private and ingonito mode, can you please help for this issue

Comment: Create a new post, explain what “stop working” means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548279/msal-net-azure-b2c-sso-is-not-working-into-incognito-mode-after-chrome-upgrade