# MSAL.NET Azure B2C SSO is not working into Incognito mode after chrome upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 applications one is asp .net application with MSAL.Net and other one is power apps application, I used iframe for silent login and it was working everywhere before chrome and firefox upgrade. After upgrading chrome and firefox browser it stop working into Incognito mode of chrome and Private mode of firefox stop working and giving below errors.
[image]
From Chrome

[image]
From Firefox

Can you please help me to resolve this issue by code instead manually do browser setting

Thanks,

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 83+ in incognito mode, has an option by default
(x) Block third-party cookies in Incognito. Disable this.

As a proper fix, use a custom domain name so that the browser no longer considers it a third party:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Hi @jas
can you please help me on this question
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380364/why-request-isauthenticated-is-false-when-token-generated-from-iframe-for-sso-az)

Answer (score 0):

In private mode, please **enable cookies** in your browser in order for msal to work properly. This information has to be added to your cookie policy as well to make the users of your application aware.