# Why Request.IsAuthenticated is false when token generated from iframe for SSO azure B2C msal .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 applications, one is mvc web application with Msal .net code for Azure ad B2C login and second application is power apps portal using same azure ad b2c login. I have added **iframe** into both application for silent login if user logged in any one of the application, on power apps portal it worked on all browser like chrome, firefox, edge, opera. But for mvc application it work only on firefox browser, other than firefox it's request does not get authenticated. When I debug **iframe** request, able to see acquire token

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity));
Globals.ClientInfo = confidentialClient;
// Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Globals.Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
Globals.AuthenticationResult = result;
Globals.Claims = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
Globals.EncryptedClaim = notification.JwtSecurityToken.RawData;
```

[image]

but into call back function Request.IsAuthenticated is false.

[image]

My web application is using .net framework 4.7.1 and Microsoft.Identity.Client version 4.29.0, please help me to resolve this issue.
Also i am getting below error for my b2c callback method on chrome and edge, automatically response cookies are getting set **Lax** instead **None**, is this causing problem to set cookies for iframe.
[image]

Thanks, 
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Request.IsAuthenticated is FALSE when you deal with `<authentication mode="Forms">` and TRUE if you deal with `<authentication mode="Windows" />`.

So, to solve this problem check the authentication mode in your web.config. Add the following code in your web.config :

```cs
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/_Login/Login" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

and

```cs
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
     <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

Set the reply URL to your main homepage URL in both the registration and the config and make sure that the application ID and client ID are matching.

Refer the following links for more information :

- [Microsoft AAD Identity And Access Management With MVC 5 Web Application.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/windows-azure-active-directory-identity-and-access-management-with-mvc-5-web-app/)
- [Request.IsAuthenticated is false after logging into Active Directory| MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82bb5edb-cca6-4ad7-9ec6-b3f788048584/requestisauthenticated-is-false-after-logging-into-active-directory?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

If in case you are getting redirected to the login page after successfull  login then you will need to change the CookieManger :

```cs
var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions();
cookieOptions.CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(); 
app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
```

Check this [document](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues) for more information.

Comment: I created new sample application with msal .net, and added your mention code but still on chrome iframe request is not get authenticated on chrome

Comment: Are you getting token timeout error or get redirected back to the login page after logging in, can you elaborate the problem so that I can help.

Comment: when request get send from iframe for silent login, In callback function Adlogincallback() as I mention in my main post image, Request.IsAutheticanted is coming as False for chrome no exception or timeout message is coming, when trying same from firefox in callback function flag is coming True.

Comment: Could you clear the cache memory and try again. If you have `CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always` in your code try commenting it and check. Also check if adding this `<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>` in the web.config works. Do your application work after login and then refreshing the page ?

Comment: Added you mention web.config setting still not work. actually i have problem with iframe request only, other than that normal login works. I want to achieve that the user logged in from power apps application, through iframe I will send request to login method to check if iframe load home page after logged in then reload page, if not then will keep user on login page to do login.